# Rails is not assigning a user id to my wiki object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm a beginner, and have been learning Ruby on Rails for about 4 months now.

I'm building a basic wiki app that is supposed to allow for private wikis. Right now, when a user creates a wiki, rails is not assigning a user id to the wiki. When I look at the wiki in the rails console, everything is there - created_at, title, body, wiki id - but the user_id is always nil. How can I fix this?

Here is my Wikis Controller:

```
class WikisController < ApplicationController
      def index

        @wikis = Wiki.all     
      end

      def new
        @wiki =Wiki.new
        authorize @wiki
      end

      def show
        @wiki = Wiki.find(params[:id])
      end

      def edit
        @wiki = Wiki.find(params[:id])
        authorize @wiki
      end

      def update
        @wiki = Wiki.find(params[:id])
        authorize @wiki
        if @wiki.update_attributes(wiki_params)
          flash[:notice] = "Wiki was updated."
          redirect_to @wiki
        else
          flash[:error] = "There was an error updating the wiki."
          render :edit
        end
      end

      def create
        @wiki = Wiki.new(wiki_params)
        authorize @wiki
        if @wiki.save
          flash[:notice] = "Wiki was saved."
          redirect_to @wiki
        else
          flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the wiki. Please try again."
          render :new
        end 
      end

      def destroy
        @wiki = Wiki.find(params[:id])
        name = @wiki.title
        if @wiki.destroy
          flash[:notice] =  "\"#{name}\" was deleted."
          redirect_to wikis_path
          else
          flash[:error] = "There was an error deleting the wiki."
          redirect_to @wiki
        end
      end
    end

    private

      def wiki_params 
        params.require(:wiki).permit(:title, :body, :private, :user_id)
      end
```

... and here are my models:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base


    def admin?
      role == 'admin'
    end

    def member?
      role == 'member'
    end

    def premium_member?
      role == 'premium_member'
    end


    has_many :collaborations
    has_many :wikis, through: :collaborations

      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

    end
```

join table...

```
class Collaboration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :wiki
end
```

wiki model...

```
class Wiki < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collaborations
  has_many :users, through: :collaborations

end
```

and finally, the schema:

```
create_table "collaborations", force: true do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "wiki_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "role",                   default: "member", null: false
    t.string   "email",                  default: "",       null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",       null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,        null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

  create_table "wikis", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "body"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "private",    default: false
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you say that a wiki `has_many :users, through: :collaborations`, then the `user_id` column on wikis will not be populated by rails automatically. Instead, it should just save the `wiki_id` with the `user_id` as a row in the `collaborations` table. Otherwise, a wiki could only have one user, right?

If you really want to save a `user_id` on the wiki table column, you could do it in a [callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) on the wiki model.